# Is there a way to backup my public key?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I want to reset my PC, but my SSH public key will also be gone. Is there a way to save it and then put it back in after that ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to backup both your private and public key. They are usually located in the directory ~/.ssh/

E.g. I have ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub which contains my public key, and ~/.ssh/id_rsa which contains my private key.

Simply backing up the folder ~/.ssh/, or your entire home directory, is probably the easiest.

Comment: So I back up the .ssh directory on an Ubuntu PC, and if I want to copy them to another PC that has Windows for example, I can just paste it into the required folder (the `user` folder) and they will work ?

Comment: I don't know where or how the keys are stored on Windows, sorry.

Comment: I just want to know if the keys will work if I transfer them to another PC

Comment: They do - there is nothing magic about them, they are just files. (But I do not use Windows, so I don't know how to handle ssh keys on that platform.)

Comment: If you are moving the keys between different OSes, you should specify that in your question as it matters a lot.